# Why are my Media Queries not Working in WordPress Weaver Xtreme theme?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have some fairly simple code which I want to be responsive:

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="article-image">
   <img class="alignright size-full wp-image-130" src="http://example.com/my-image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="outlook-text">Article text blah blah ...</div>
```

CSS Code works to put the text in a column on the left and the image on the right under the title:

```css
.outlook-text {
   float:left;
   width:47%;
   line-height:1.8em;
}

.article-image {
   float:right;
   width:47%;
}

.article-image img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

On smaller screens, I want to be able to put the image above the text and scale both divs to 100%:

```css
/* On screens that are 600px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

   .outlook-text {
        width:100%;
   }

   .article-image {
      width:100%;
   }

}
```

The media query has no effect. Any ideas? Must be something simple, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Is it article-text or outlook-text in media query

Comment: should be outlook-text. My typo, but this isn't the problem in the actual code which I simplified for purposes of asking my question. Thanks for catching that, though.

Comment: I edited the answer with a !important flag

Comment: No change with or without !important

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a typo in media query. It should be

```
    /* On screens that are 600px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
     { 

    .outlook-text { width:100% !important; } 
    .article-image { width:100% !important; }

     }
```

Comment: Check by place a !important to CSS. Might be some CSS overwrite your media query

Comment: @Dave Hmm, media query looks good. Can you check the browser developer tool to ensure CSS is displayed when you shrink the window (lesser than 600px). Might be your CSS applied correctly but any outer components causes the problem. You can easily check by adding a background color to element in media query